# generate 'next ifs' from config file in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, configuration

there is something in Perl I don't know how to code, can I request your help please.

basically, I'm trying to use a configuration file with an array (or a hash or anything of that sort) containing "exceptions" that I want to use in a "next if" of a loop of the main program.

exemple :

my program looks like that :

```
while(<>) {
    next if /regex1/;
    next if /regex2/;
    next if /regexN/;
}
```

and I want to be able to put these "next if" from a config file, like :

```
my %conf = do './config_file.conf';
while(<>) {
    # put code here to add all 'next ifs';
}
```

config file example :

```
exceptions   =>   [
                    'regex1',
                    'regex2',
                    'regexN',
                  ],
```

how can I do this easily in my code ? (where the comment is, that is, adding all "next if" from an array

thanks !
regards,

Comment: Please review the new answers. Mine is not wrong, but badly inefficient. I'd appreciate if you unaccept it so I can remove it as it's misleading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### This is very inefficient! Don't do this. You should pre-compile the pattern instead.

You can use a another loop to iterate over all your patterns inside of your `while`. If you assign a label to your `while` loop you can `next` that directly.

```
my %conf = ( exceptions => [ 'regex1', 'regex2', 'regexN', ], );

OUTER: while (<DATA>) {
    foreach my $re (@{ $conf{exceptions} }) {
        next OUTER if m/$re/;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
regex0
regex1
regex2
regexA
regexB
regexN
```

This will output

```
regex0
regexA
regexB
```

---

Note that the `do './config_file.conf'` is very safe. You should use a module to read a config file format instead. That will make your code more portable and make sure no code you might not control gets executed. For example, you could use [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON), or [Config::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Config::Simple).

Comment: If you have **a lot** of lines to check, it might be cheaper to compile all of them into a single large pattern.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't about the fact that I could control the "next" of an outer block, thanks !

Comment: btw I made it work with a grep in a table too, example above

Comment: That's actually pretty awful. it compiles up to three patterns for every lines, instead of compiling one (or even three) patterns.

Comment: @ikegami I know. I'm not thinking straight today. But it's accepted, so I can't remove it any more.

Answer (score 4):

Don't compile the patterns over and over again as simbabque and olivierg have recommended!

```
my %conf = ( exceptions => [ 'regex1', 'regex2', 'regexN', ], );

my $exceptions_re = join '|', @{ $conf{exceptions} };
$exceptions_re = qr/$exceptions_re/;

while (<DATA>) {
   next if /$re/;
   print;
}
```

---

If what you claim are regex patterns are actually strings to match literally, change

```
my $exceptions_re = join '|', @{ $conf{exceptions} };
```

to

```
my $exceptions_re = join '|', map quotemeta, @{ $conf{exceptions} };
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers - I'd probably expand it to compile up a regex from my input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %conf = ( exceptions => [ 'regex1', 'regex2', 'regexN', ], );

my $match = join ( "|", @{$conf{exceptions}} ); 
   $match = qr/\b$match\b/;

print "Using regex of: ",$match,"\n";

while ( <DATA> ) {
   next if /$match/;
   print;
}

__DATA__
regex0
regex1
regex2
regexA
regexB
regexN
```

This has an advantage over `grep` in particular, that grep will iterate the whole list of regex, even if it hits a match early on. That won't matter noticeably if you've a small number of patterns though.

For bonus points, you may want to sort by likelihood of 'hit', so a match is located earlier on. By default, sorting by length might do it.

(And note - I use `\b` word boundary anchors, which may not be what you want to do, given you are using regex as input)

Answer (score 0):

mmh it seems working with :

```
next if grep /$_/, @{$conf{exceptions}};
```

don't know if it's really clean tho

any other idea ?

Comment: @simbabque This is equivalent to `next if grep { $_ =~ /$_/ } @{$conf{exceptions}};`, so it's just plain wrong. It also checks every single pattern needlessly.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot as I just said above, I'm not really thinking straight today. Sorry.